# How to create multiple SQlite tables using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, database, function, sqlite, cordova

So far in my app development (phonegap/JQuery Mobile) I have setup a database and have a table created to which I have implemented a few functions that interact with the table for different events e.g. user registration.

However, I need to create another table within the same database however I'm not sure how to go about this.

I attempted to created another function (createEvent(tx) {) that creates a table however that isn't working.

Please see my javascript below which builds the database and creates the table with.

```
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

                     var db;
                     function onDeviceReady() {
                         db = window.openDatabase("SoccerEarth", "2.0", "SoccerEarthDB", 2*1024*1024);
                         db.transaction(createDB, createEvents, errorCB, successCB);

                     }
                     function createDB(tx) {
                         tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SoccerEarth (UserName text, FirstName text, LastName text, Email text, Password text, CPass text)');

                     }
                     function createEvents(tx) {
                     tx.execute2('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SoccerEvents (Title text, Location text, NoPeople text, Date text, Description text)');
                                              }

                     function errorCB(err) {
                         alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
                     }

                     function successCB() {
                  alert("Database Ready!");
                     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this, just for simplicity:

```
db.transaction(function (tx) {            
tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SoccerEarth (UserName text, FirstName text, LastName text, Email text, Password text, CPass text)');
tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SoccerEvents (Title text, Location text, NoPeople text, Date text, Description text)');
 }, errorCB, successCB);
```

Comment: Thanks, I see my mistake. I accidentaly typed execute2 instead of executeSql for the 2nd table.

Comment: @Mahdi Please accept this as the answer if it answered your question. I know it did mine :).

Comment: @KendallRoth Done :)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the SQL statement as an array of string something. and execute each statement in the array.

```
var sql = [ "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LEAD (ID VARCHAR(35) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, PROCESS VARCHAR (32), VERSION VARCHAR (8), CREATED_BY VARCHAR (128), CREATED_ON VARCHAR (32), RECIPIENT VARCHAR (32), STATUS VARCHAR (8))",
         "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DOCUMENT (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, LEAD_ID VARCHAR(35) REFERENCES LEAD (ID) NOT NULL, NAME VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL, TYPE VARCHAR (32) NOT NULL, CONTENT BLOB NOT NULL, RETRY INTEGER NOT NULL, STATUS VARCHAR (8))",
         "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FUNDATA(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, FUN_ID INTEGER REFERENCES LEAD (ID), NAME VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL, VALUE VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL)"  ];
```

now pass all the sql to function which would execute , also pass your database object .
Callback can be any other function.

```
function write(database, sql){
    this.sql = sql;
    database.transaction(
      function(tx){
      for(var i=0; i<this.sql.length; i++){
      console.log("execute sql : " + this.sql[i]);
      tx.executeSql(this.sql[i]);
    }    
      },function(error){
    console.log("error call back : " + JSON.stringify(error));
    console.log(error);
  },
     function(){
    console.log("transaction complete call back ");
  }
    );  
  }
```

Hope it provides a better way of doing things and making the code more robust .You could also execute Insert statement like this.